# Sul significato e la storia dell'espressione "levare mano"

Tags: meaning, regional, history

Nel romanzo *Ferito a morte*, di Raffaele La Capria, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Alle sue spalle parlano ancora del Venezuela. Glauco dopo lo sfogo s’è calmato, ora sembrano tutti presi dalla voglia di andarsene con lui, nel gruppo circola una brezzolina di euforia, parlano dei milioni di Dodero... Milioni? Miliardi, vuoi dire. Più di Onassis. – Che faresti tu coi soldi di Dodero? E che farebbe Dodero coi soldi miei, quello voglio vedere, pure lui buttato sopra la terrazza di un Circolo sotto un sole cocente! Sì sì, meglio **levare mano**, te ne vai in Venezuela, paese giovane, per lo meno non vedi più le stesse facce! Come fa Elio che ogni tanto scompare, sai che è partito, e quando ritorna tutti s’interessano a lui.

Si tratta di un romanzo ambientato a Napoli.

Quando ho letto questo brano mi sono accorta di non capire il significato dell'espressione "levare mano" e ho cominciato a ricercare.

Ho cercato alle voci "mano" e "levare" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa locuzione (ho trovato sul Treccani e altri "levare le mani al cielo", "levare di mano le botte", "levare di mano a un santo", "levare di mano la palla a qualcuno", ma non credo abbiano niente a che vedere).

Ho visto che questa locuzione appare su questo [Dizionario etimologico di meridionalismi](http://sites.unice.fr/site/henneboi/SVG-lirces/langues/real/dialectes/legnare.htm). I dizionari citati sono il *Vocabolario siciliano* di Piccitto e il *Nuovo Dizionario dialettale della Calabria* di Rohlfs. Anche l'autore citato che fa uso di "levare mano", Santiapichi, è sicilano. Secondo questi dizionari, in Sicilia significa "smettere di lavorare" e in Calabria "interrompere, sospendere un lavoro". È anche questo il senso che ha questa espressione a Napoli? Cioè, il significato nel brano di La Capria sarebbe "meglio smettere di lavorare e andarsene in Venezuela"?

Ecco un altro esempio di un autore siciliano, Giosué Calaciura, tratto dal suo libro [*Pantelleria. L'ultima isola*](https://books.google.es/books?id=5qCODAAAQBAJ&pg=PT24&lpg=PT24&dq=%22levare+mano%22&source=bl&ots=50vSqJ2GSX&sig=ACfU3U2zbGoaeSeL9gSmBXw_gFlq3au0Ng&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj8oMGk_rrrAhWKGBQKHSsZDucQ6AEwEHoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22levare%20mano%22&f=false), in cui il significato è chiaramente "smettere di lavorare":

> È un ritorno, in chiave di modernità accettabile, alla dignità del lavoro manuale. Duro. Dieci raccolte, da maggio a fine agosto, spesso strisciando per terra per adeguarsi al portamento della pianta, senza ausili meccanici, dalle prime luci dell'alba sino a mezzogiorno, quando il calore del sole costringe a **levare mano**. Nella cesta, in un'ora, non più di due chili.

Tuttavia, ho trovato anche questo testo provveniente da un [giornale della Campania](http://www.irpinianews.it/basket-caos-nel-mondo-cestistico-la-scandone-attende/), che mi fa pensare che il senso di questa locuzione in tale regione possa essere leggermente diverso:

> Ma quale tipo di campionato la squadra avellinese sarà pronta ad affrontare? I tifosi meritano di vedere un campionato di vertice, altrimenti sarebbe meglio **levare mano**. Che senso avrebbe fare un campionato di basso livello e di passione anche in legadue? Nessuno, ciò contribuirebbe solo ad allontanare i tifosi dal palazzetto.

Curiosamente, però, ho trovato questa espressione nel [tomo IV, parte seconda dell'*Archivio storico italiano, ossia raccolta di opere e documenti finora inediti o divenuti rarissimi riguardanti la storia d'Italia*](https://archive.org/details/pt2archiviostori04depuuoft/page/n19/mode/2up), pubblicato al Gabinetto Visieux di Firenze nel  1853. In questo libro si trova una sezione intitolata "Voci e maniere degne d'osservazione che s'incontrano in questo Volume" in cui appare "levare mano" definito come "cessar di fare una cosa". L'espressione appare alla pagina 174 in un testo  Cinquecentesco sulla vita di [Antonio Giacomini](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/antonio-giacomini-tebalducci_%28Dizionario-Biografico%29/), fiorentino, scritto da [Iacopo Pitti](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/iacopo-pitti_(Dizionario-Biografico)/), anche fiorentino.

Anche in questa [*Raccolta di tutte le voci scoperte sul vocabolario ultimo della Crusca e aggiunta di altre che ivi mancano di Dante, Petrarca e Boccaccio*](https://books.google.es/books?id=TdY_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22levare+mano%22+cessar&source=bl&ots=Pgfxu2ud2i&sig=ACfU3U1fgQejI8tWFrT5Ec5EQZkj8v4WdA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwij197fpbfrAhWh3OAKHQBYDwAQ6AEwAnoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22levare%20mano%22%20cessar&f=false), pubblicato a Venezia nel 1760, appare la locuzione "levare mano" definita come

> Dessistere. Finire. Cessar di fare.

E nel libro [*Niccolò Machiavelli e i suoi tempi*, vol. I](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/61704) di Pasquale Villari, si trova una lettera dei Dieci al Commissario T. Tosinghi, del 3 ottobre 1504, in cui si legge (grassetto mio):

> Noi intendiamo quello che voi dite della difficultà che ha cotesta sboccatura ad cavarsi, rispetto alla strada et alla grotta dove è el terreno più fermo et più forte che in tucta la coda del fosso; intendiamo come fra sei dì credete haverla fornita, secondo el parlare di cotesti capi maestri, et come e' se ne potrebbono ingannare, etc.; et examinato con quante difficultà vi si conducono gli huomini, et con quanta, condocti vi sono, voi ve gli mantenete, stiamo con dispiacere in qualche parte di questa cosa; perchè, scorciandosi el tempo, giudichiamo che bisognerà **levare mano** subito, veggiendo maxime la voglia di coteste genti d'arme, et quando el tempo non si scorciassi, la pagha delle fanterie ci è addosso.

Anche nel libro [*Les origines politiques des guerres de religion. Henri II et l'Italie (1547-1555). D'après des Documents originaux inédits*](https://archive.org/details/lesoriginespolit01romi) si trova questa frase tratta da una lettera del 1547 da J. Alvarotti al duca di Ferrara:

> S. M<sup>tà</sup> ha falto **levare mano** a tutte le fabriche che facea il Re suo padre.

Leggendo la frase nel libro, il suo senso sembra essere che il re Enrico II di Valois fece smettere l'attività che si svolgeva in tali fabbriche.

Un altro esempio di uso di "levare mano" si trova nel libro [*Il chirone in campo, tomo secondo, o sia, La chirurgia svelata*](https://books.google.es/books?id=S6013q0FWTMC&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq=%22levare+mano%22&source=bl&ots=Pglak64AdY&sig=ACfU3U0wNe9_8JxnZ9Ndk4jlR97t4e6yEQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZu8iP6dTrAhX5A2MBHckhD4YQ6AEwCXoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22levare%20mano%22&f=false), pubblicato a Venezia nel 1729:

> Non si essendo in tal tempo osservato altro che una certa febbricciatola, la quale venuta sulla sera de' sei, tirò avanti fin' al mezzodì del dì vegnente, nel qual tempo, il Paziente se ne trovò libero. Lo stesso dì de' dieci fù stimato bene il **levare mano** a i brodi alteranti, attesa la troppa languidezza delle prime vie.

Quindi, potrebbe trattarsi di un'espressione che in passato era più diffusa e che, per qualche ragione, sia soppravvisuta  soltanto nel sud Italia? Forse nell'*Archivio storico italiano* pubblicato al Gabinetto Visieux si spiegava il significato dell'espressione perché nel 1853 era caduta in disuso da tempo in Toscana? Qualcuno saprebbe spiegare qualcosa sulla storia di questa locuzione?

Comment: Qui il significato è evidentemente quello di andarsene, mollare tutto, scappare, darsi alla fuga - un'espressione molto più utilizzata sarebbe probabilmente "levare le tende".
Mi incuriosisce capire da dove potrebbe derivare questa espressione - che non ho mai sentito - non so perché, all'orecchio mi suona come una qualche derivazione dal latino... "Manus" in latino significa anche "truppa"... che sia una cosa del tipo "levare le truppe" (quindi qualcosa tipo ritirarsi, battere in ritirata)? Sto un po' andando a caso.

Comment: Mai sentito questa espressione. Il senso sembra essere “meglio togliersi di torno”. Da un altro sito leggo che forse deriva dal latino “manus levare” ossia smettere di fare qualcosa. Sembra essere usata nel dialetto napoletano.

Comment: @Hachi sono convinto tu abbia ragione! Non ricordavo "manus levare" = smettere (mollare tutto)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi - si da cui dovrebbe derivare l’espressione legale di “manleva”. https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/M/manleva.html

Comment: @Charo. - in realtà nel dizionario che citi in entrambi i casi il significato è smettere di fare qualcosa (un lavoro, un’attività ). Portar via, togliere e riferito solo a levare. Posso solo immaginare che in napoletano non abbia un significato tanto diverso.

Comment: Hai ragione, @Hachi: corretto.

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Adesso il senso mi sembra di più quello di togliere le mani di qualcosa (il lavoro o una certa attività) che ha bisogno delle mani per potersi svolgere.

Comment: A me sembra che "meglio smettere di lavorare e andarsene in Venezuela" sia un'interpretazione ragionevole.

Comment: Sì, @RiccardoDeContardi: è che all'inizio non avevo pensato che potesse essere un regionalismo,  quindi non avevo cercato in questo dizionario. E poi, quando l'ho trovato, non ho interpretato bene l'informazione (perciò il commento di Hachi). Per questa ragione, la domanda è stata aggiornata parecchie volte.

Comment: @Hachi: Tuttavia sembra che in passato si usasse anche in toscano.

Comment: @Charo - può essere, derivando dal latino può avere attecchito in diverse regioni. In italiano sopravvive soltanto l’espressione formale “manlevare”.